# Hypergeometric ${}_2F_0$ function in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions

How to write the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_0$ in Mathematica?

Comment: `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z]` is the straight answer, but depending on what you're doing, you may be better off with formulating things in terms of Tricomi's function, `HypergeometricU[]`.

Comment: Are you sure that ${}_2F_0$ is well-defined? I am unable to find any parameters $a$, $b$, $z$ for which `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z]` gives something other than `ComplexInfinity`. Also, `Sum[Pochhammer[a, k] Pochhammer[b, k] z^k/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]` remains unevaluated in Mathematica, does not give a ${}_2F_0$ function.

Comment: @Roman When a and b have an opposite sign, eg {a,b}={-3,2}, the results seems ok and is a polynomial in z.

Comment: @Roman, ${}_2F_0$ is indeed a function defined as the analytic continuation of a certain divergent power series (see e.g. [this](https://fungrim.org/symbol/Hypergeometric2F0/)).

Comment: @Hans: the correct statement is that if any of `a` and `b` in `HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z]` are nonpositive integers, then you have a polynomial result (since all the Pochhammer symbols after a certain point zero out).

Comment: Some comments appeared while I was typing...

`HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z]` is divergent (just like all $_pF_q$ with $p-q\geq2$), but can be expanded into a power series around $z=0$. Only if $a$ or $b$ is a negative integer, the series stops when the Pochhammer symbol hits zero, leading to polynomials.

Note that the divergent series can be regularized, and `Sum[Pochhammer[a, k] Pochhammer[b, k] z^k/k!, {k, 0, ∞}, Regularization -> "Borel"]` gives
`(-(1/z))^a HypergeometricU[a, 1 + a - b, -(1/z)]`

Comment: ...and the last expression in @Fred's comment is exactly why I said it might be better to reformulate in terms of `HypergeometricU[]`.

Comment: @J.M. You are of course right, I stand corrected!!! :-)

Comment: Very interesting, guys! Thank you. @FredHucht how did you know to use Borel regularization (apart from all others not converging)?

Comment: Never mind, [I found it](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Borel-RegularizedSum.html). Interesting stuff!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the many comments, it appears that the correct function is

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z]
```

You can confirm the correspondence to the traditional form

```
HypergeometricPFQ[{a, b}, {}, z] // TraditionalForm
```

This outputs something like $$\, _2F_0(a,b;;z)$$